# Настройка выпадающей контактной формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<a href="#open-block" class="phonetell">Заказать обратный звонок</a>
  <div class="contactwrap">
    <div class="formwrap">
    <h2>Обратный звонок</h2>
      <form action="URL" class='clearfix'> 
       <div class="left">
         <p>Ваше имя</p>
         <input type="text" value="Имя">
        </div>
         <div class="right">
           <p>Ваш номер телефона</p>
           <input type="text" value='Телефон'>
         </div>
         <div>
       <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
       </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

При клике на ссылку **.phonetell** открывается окно формы отправки, но при клике на него, форма пропадает. Ниже вылаживаю код JS который писал:

```
$(function() {
  $('.phonetell').click(function () {
    $('.contactwrap').fadeIn('slow');
  })
  $('.contactwrap').click(function () {
    $('.contactwrap').fadeOut('slow');
  })
});
```

Подскажите, что нужно исправить в коде, чтобы выпадающее окно закрывалось только при нажимании кнопки **"Отправить"** или мимо окна **.formwrap**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Само собой пропадает. Вы же в коде и указываете что при клике на `.contactwrap` скрыть `.contactwrap`. Используйте [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) чтобы окно не закрывалось при клике на `.contactwrap` и ссылку, а в остальных случаях - скрывать.

Например так:

```js
$('.phonetell').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.contactwrap').fadeIn('slow');
});

$('.contactwrap').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})

$(document).click(function() {
  $('.contactwrap').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.contactwrap {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#open-block" class="phonetell">Заказать обратный звонок</a>
<div class="contactwrap">
  <div class="formwrap">
    <h2>Обратный звонок</h2>
    <form action="URL" class='clearfix'>
      <div class="left">
        <p>Ваше имя</p>
        <input type="text" value="Имя">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p>Ваш номер телефона</p>
        <input type="text" value='Телефон'>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

`fadeOut()` при нажатии на "отправить" соответственно надо прописывать в том месте кода, где происходит отправка.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня .contactwrap на весь экран (ширина и высота 100%), такой скрипт не уберет окно совсем, может как-то это можно поправить ?

Comment: а на hide/show не вариант ?

Comment: @SvArt713 Видимо примерно так: [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/w0zxf289/) Особо ничего не меняется, только `stopPropagation()` применять к `formwrap`.

Comment: Alexander Igorevich   ваш ответ идеальный - я не автор но круто

Comment: Не понял, что значит "hide/show"?

Comment: Alexander Igorevich, Спасибо большое, теперь все работает как нужно! ))